# Difference between conics

Tags: conic-sections, quadratic-forms

My university course handout this formula is written: $Ax^2 + 2Bxy+ Cy^2+ 2Dx + 2Ey + F=0$ but I see more results on Google with this one: $Ax^2 + Bxy+ Cy^2+ Dx + Ey + F=0$.

In my seminar, we always don't care about the 2 but It still confuses me. Each time I see the formula, and the following example: $5x^2 + 8xy + 3y^2+ 2x + 6y + 1$, I want to divide by $2$ to get the "real" $B$, $D$ or $E$. Here, for me, It would be: $A = 5, B = 4, C = 3, D = 1, E = 3, F = 1$.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the MSE community. You have written $Ax^2 + 2Bxy+ Cy^2+ 2Dx + 2Ey + F=0$ two times.

Comment: Are you asking what the purpose of the 2 is?

Comment: @DavidRaveh Yes, more or less. Why is it present for the first, but not on the second, whilst both are correct. I edited, you may have seen the old where It was the same formula: copy/paste typo.

Comment: I agree that the 2s are better because they simplify completing the square. I recommend you stick with your course handout, or you’re going to get very confused.

Comment: It's a matter of convention or mathematical convenient.  Make sure your notation or convention consistent throughout your work.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I see the equation written in the form
$$f(\textbf{x})=ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+g$$
This form is useful because it easily allows us to express the function in the form
$$f(\textbf{x})=\textbf{x}^TH\textbf{x}+\textbf{x}^T\textbf{h}+g$$
where $H$ is the matrix with $a$ and $c$ along the diagonal and $b$ on the off-diagonals, and $\textbf{h}$ is the vector with entries $d$ and $e$. The matrix $H$ is thus symmetric, and can be diagonalized to rotate this quadratic and express it in the form of an ellipse or hyperbola centered at zero with rotated and translated axes.

So, the purpose of the $2$ is just to help you make the matrix symmetric.

Comment: I suspect the level of this answer is perhaps not aimed correctly.